# why I have output like this for make pair in siamese network?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

This is my code, and I take the output that illustrates the below. Len of idx is 1000. I want to make image pairs and label pairs, but I take errors like this:

Code:

```
pair_images = []
pair_labels = []
new_labels = []

for k in labels:
    new_labels.append(int(k))

numClasses  = len(np.unique(new_labels))

new_labels = np.array(new_labels)

idx = [np.where(new_labels == i)[0] for i in range(0,numClasses)]


for idxA in range(len(images)):


    # Make Posetive Images
    currentImage = images[idxA]
    label = new_labels[idxA]


    idxB = np.random.choice(idx[label])
    posImage = images[idxB]
```

output:

```
    idxB = np.random.choice(idx[label])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has some really good tools for these kinds of tasks

Comment: What's the output of `print(idx[label])`? It looks like you're trying to access `idx` like a dictionary when it's an array.

Comment: Instead of label would it be idx.